# Object oriented programming: Point objects transferred into a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I need to define an object class, Polyline. And the argument should be a list of tuples, representing the x,y values for the coordinates of the vertices.

```
class Polyline:
    def __init__(self, points):
        point = (point[0], point[1])
        for i in range(0,len(point)):
            self.points.append(tuple(point[i]))
```

I know the code does not make sense, but I can't wrap my head around it. I want the points variable to be a list of tuples made up of point objects.

So this should be valid for instance.

```
poly = Polyline[(2,4),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

Comment: You have some syntax problems. For instance, the class instance is constructed with parentheses, not square brackets. If you’re trying to pass a list of points, you need to wrap that list in parentheses.

Comment: I added some extra content about dataclasses to my answer, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you're making things too difficult for yourself. Because you've already created the list of points, you should just store it.

```
class Polyline:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points
```

---

You can now create a `Polyline`:

```
poly = Polyline([(2,4),(3,4),(4,5)])
```

Or if you want to provide a stored list:

```
my_points = [(2,4),(3,4),(4,5)]
poly = Polyline(my_points)
```

Note that either way, you need parentheses—as I noted in my comment up above.

---

Now, let's verify that it worked. We'll print the contents:

```
for point in poly.points:
    print(point)
# (2, 4)
# (3, 4)
# (4, 5)
```

---

### Dataclasses: a diatribe

Oh, and not that you asked—but Python provides a way to make your `Polyline` class instantly more useful, for free. You can automatically get:

- Better equality comparison (compared to the default, which is just based on pointer)
- Better representation when you print it
- An automatic `__init__` method.

Here's the way: [make it a `dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass  # Requires Python ≥ 3.7
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Polyline:
    points: List  # For simplicity. Should really be List[Tuple[int, int]]
# That's it!

# Now let's make one and show you the magic.

# Automatically, you get an initializer.
my_points = [(2,4),(3,4),(4,5)]
poly = Polyline(my_points)

# Automatically, you get better string representation for printing.
print(poly)
# Polyline(points=[(2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5)])

# Automatically, you get a correct equality comparison.
poly2 = Polyline([(2,4),(3,4),(4,5)])
print(poly == poly2)
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue in your code is that

```
poly = Polyline[(2,4), (3,4) ,(4, 5)]
```

Is not a valid way to make an instance of a class, it should look like

```
poly = Polyline([(2,4), (3,4), (4,5)])
```

Second, and perhaps more importantly, there is no variable in this that is per-instance. You would need something like

```
class Polyline
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points
```

Once this is done you should have a class that stores a list of tupples.